# Is there any way to directly access the baked lighting data present in a MapBuildDataRegistry file?

Tags: c++, encoding, unreal-engine5, light, unreal-blueprint

I am working on a project that involves getting the final color of a material hit by a raycast. There are hacky ways to accomplish this, but as I can't swap the final pre-render GPU buffer back to the CPU without severe performance issues, there's no real way to get the color of any asset hit.

I believe baked lighting maps would contain the data I'm looking for, and Unreal Engine 5 builds that lighting data into a MapBuildDataRegistry file (technically a .uasset file with that type.) Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to access that data, through blueprints, c++, or even direct file reading as it's encoded in a way none of my programs can parse. If there is a way to access the lighting data in these files, it's not documented anywhere I've found.

Does anyone know if these files are accessible in any way? My project is currently based on blueprints, but if there is a way to do this through c++ I'd convert it in an instant.

Comment: I've made some progress on this! Will write up a full answer once I'm 100% sure things are working.